# Url redirect with symbols on Wordpress with .htacces

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've got a URL with something like this:

`www.google.com/?attachment_id=837`

I want all the pages with an attachment to go to the homepage, for SEO reasons, I do not want those URLs to appear in a google search. I try to delete with Yaogast plugin, but I think the theme that is on the page is not coded "right".
I want to redirect to the home for example.

I tried something like this, and variations:

`redirect 301 /?attachment_id=837 http://google.com`

`RewriteRule ?attachment_id(.*) / [R=301, L]`

I think that "?" and "=" in the URL is giving me some problems.

Answer (score 0):

The "?" indicates a GET variable. You cannot use URL Rewriting over GET variables. Changing your .htaccess will not help. I think the best thing to do here is to use the GET variable in the PHP file. Access your PHP file from wordpress, and add this code in the beginning:

```
if(isset($_GET['attachment_id'])) header('Location: redirect_url');
```

And replace "redirect_url" with the url you want to redirect to